# mocking out this.props.dispatch nested in a router and Provider components

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to write a unit test for my code which is nested in a Provider in a Router.  My component uses redux by calling this.props.dispatch(ACTION).  In order to test this i need to mock out this.props.dispatch in my test but I'm not able to do this.

It seems like for some reason the issue is that Login is nested within Provider and a Router component which causes Login to ignore any kind of mocked out prop I pass it.  If you look at the commented out line of code it works - The only difference is that Login component is not nested within Provider and a Router in this example.

So my question is, is there something extra I am supposed to do if I want to mock out the props of a nested component like this?

```
describe("Pokedex", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        var dispatch = jest.fn();
        var props = {
            dispatch
        };
        // wrapper = mount(<Login {...props} />); Correctly mocks dispatch
        wrapper = mount(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router >
                    <Login {...props} />
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        );
        wrapper.setState({ loading: false });
        store.clearActions();
    });
```

Part of Login Component:

```
export class Login extends PureComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("Props", this.props.dispatch);

        this.props.dispatch(userActions.resetError());

        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        };

/** Extra code omitted **/

    }
```

Comment: By using Provider you're supplying a *real* dispatcher. If you want a mock, do e.g. `<Login dispatch={jest.fn()} />` on the *unwrapped* component.

Comment: But the component uses the Provider to get the state and also I get an error about not wrapping it in a Router component.

Comment: Well 1. you have to provide the values from the store too; and 2. that's related to the Router, not the Provider.

Comment: How do I provide the values from the store?  Would login component take a store prop?

Comment: Well, you know you mapStateToProps? Just... *pass those props*. That's the point of using the *unwrapped* component.

Comment: Oh, makes sense I'll give that a shot

Comment: It worked!  Feel free to make that an answer and i'll give you credit,.